# How to transform some PHP lines to function and call?

Tags: php

I get this lines on web and just created a function name to that.
The problem is: it is not working anymore and I dont know why, already tried things but nothing. Can someone help me please?

Code:

```
 <?php
    require 'PDOClasses/connection.php';
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    function ShowCategories() {
        $query = $db->query("SELECT id, name FROM categories ORDER BY name ASC");
        $option = '';
        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
        }
    }
?>
```

This is how I used to call:

```
<select id="category" name="category" tabindex="16" required>
   <?php echo $option; ?>
</select>
```

This is how I'm calling now:

```
<select id="category" name="category" tabindex="16" required>
   <?php ShowCategories(); ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are neither returning the value inside the function or echoing it.Do it like this

```
function ShowCategories() {
        $query = $db->query("SELECT id, name FROM categories ORDER BY name ASC");
        $option = '';
        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
        }
        return $option;
    }
```

Then while calling

```
<select id="category" name="category" tabindex="16" required>
   <?php echo ShowCategories(); ?>
</select>
```

or you can directly echo the `$option` inside the function itself.Like

```
echo $options;
```

instead of returning it.

Comment: @user3310429 his solution works for me, are you receiving any errors?

Comment: Please check the ShowCategories() function, whether it is fetching the data form db or not.

Comment: <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: db in <b>/home/place269/public_html/ingbook.com.br/PDOClasses/Business/show_categories.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object in <b>/home/place269/public_html/ingbook.com.br/PDOClasses/Business/show_categories.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />

Comment: So the PDO is unable to connect to your database.Please check the database connection details.

Comment: It works in old way.. without function and calling option

Comment: You are using procedural type of coding so,the connection object i.e the $db is not available inside your function.Either get the connection inside the function or create a function which will return a  connection object to you and call that function inside the function in which you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

> **The problem here is you are not printing content to the HTML Page. So**
>   **you after generating HTML string you will need to `echo` the string.**

your code will look like this.

```
<?php
function ShowCategories() {
        $query = $db->query("SELECT id, name FROM categories ORDER BY name ASC");
        $option = '<option value=''>--Please select--</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
        }
        echo $option;
    }
?>
```

in HTML now you can use the existing syntax.

```html
<select id="category" name="category" tabindex="16" required>
   <?php ShowCategories(); ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry by mistake i had used echo statement in html part. My apologize.

Comment: That happens @Pratik Soni .But its better to return inside the function and echo it while calling.

Comment: Yes that's fine way. +1 -:)

Answer (score 2):

$db is undefined in your function. Either pass it as argument or use "global"

and add echo $option in the end

Comment: Yes you are correct. Its better to make the connection as global or or pass to the function as an argument instead of creating the connection inside the function.+1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

It is working like this

```
    <?php
    function ShowCategories() {
        require 'PDOClasses/connection.php';
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        $query = $db->query("SELECT id, name FROM categories ORDER BY name ASC");
        $option = '<option value="">Selecione uma categoria</option>';
        while($category = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $option .= '<option value = "'.$category['id'].'">'.$category['name'].'</option>';
        }
        echo $option;
    }
<?php ShowCategories(); ?>
```

Comment: Yes that will work fine but make small chnages to that.

Comment: Yes it will.But don,t echo inside the while loop, rather echo it outside the loop ,and if you are you echoing there please remove echo while calling.

Comment: Changed. Thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure @user3310429. Please accept the answer if it work for you.

Comment: Done! Thank you again :)